# Binding function arguments in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'd like to generically "pickle" function calls so they can be executed later. The return type of those functions will always be `void` (for now). Something like this:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
std::function<void()> 
pickle(F function, Args&&... args) {
    return std::bind(F, args...);
}
```

The problem is, if `args` contains a const reference, `std::bind` tries to copy construct the value, which is not always desired or even valid if the type lacks a copy constructor. How do I forward the arguments in a way that uses `std::ref` for lvalue references and the normal `std::forward` for lvalue references?

#### Example

```
#include <functional>

class NonCopyable {
public:

    NonCopyable() {}

    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};

template<typename F, typename... Args>
std::function<void()>
pickle(F function, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::bind(function, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    NonCopyable obj;
    auto f = pickle(
        [](const NonCopyable&) {},
        obj
    );
    return 0;
}
```

The above snippet won't compile, complaining about the deleted copy constructor. (I used forward here because someone suggested it, but has since deleted their answer, it seems).

Comment: What do you mean by "Passes values by value"? Each type in the `Args` argument pack will be either an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference

Comment: looks relevant: "The arguments to bind are copied or moved, and are never passed by reference unless wrapped in std::ref or std::cref." http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: @AndyProwl Ah, you are right. I'd actually like it to depend on F's signature. If it expects an argument by value, it should be bound by value, and so on.

Comment: Then the solution is going to get a little more complicated than what has been proposed so far I believe, but it's doable

Comment: @Benjamin: That is only possible if you pass a (member) function pointer, not in the general case for a function object, as the `operator()` can be overloaded.

Comment: Nevermind. Xeo's answer seems to do what I need. I'll try to rephrase the question to be more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overloading, yay.

```
// also does the correct thing for `T const`
template<class T>
std::reference_wrapper<T> maybe_ref(T& v, int){ return std::ref(v); }

// just forward rvalues along
template<class T>
T&& maybe_ref(T&& v, long){ return std::forward<T>(v); }

template<typename F, typename... Args>
std::function<void()> 
pickle(F function, Args&&... args) {
    return std::bind(function, maybe_ref(std::forward<Args>(args), 0)...);
}
```

The `int`/`long` parameters and `0` argument disambiguate the lvalue case for compilers that find the overloads to be ambiguous, and doesn't do any harm otherwise.

Comment: The problem is the return value, std::function<void()> is not ok.

Comment: @mfontanini: No, `std::function<void()>` is special - it just swallows any return value.

Comment: [GCC says ambiguous call](http://liveworkspace.org/code/yJL1f$19): bug? (Works on Clang 3.2)

Comment: @AndyProwl, yes, fixable with `typename enable_if<!is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, T>::type&&` as the return type of the rvalue overload, c.f. `_S_maybe_wrap_ref` in GCC's `<future>`

Comment: I was in the process of saying the same thing anyway :)

Comment: @Andy: Partial ordering should say that the `T&` overload is more-specialized. I think. If it isn't, any easy fix not involving `enable_if` is just having an extra `int` / `long` parameter and passing `0` in the expansion.

Comment: @Jonathan: Did you mean that GCC has a bug, or my code? I thought partial ordering would make the first overload preferred, but maybe I'm getting my standardese wrong.

Comment: I meant to ask if there is a bug in GCC, as the code seems OK to me

Comment: @Xeo, I mean it's a GCC bug  (or I think it is) - maybe I should have said "workaroundable" not fixable. I can't remember if it's in bugzilla already and can't check as gcc.gnu.org is being upgraded

Comment: Notice though, that this doesn't actually do what the OP asked - although that's understandable, since the question wasn't formulated very precisely.

Comment: @BenjaminKloster: But this won't decide how to pass based on the type of the parameters of `F`, only on the types of the arguments you pass to `pickle()`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit ugly (overuse of `enable_if`), but it works:

```
template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<
  !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, T &&>::type
  forward_as_ref(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type &t) {
    return static_cast<T &&>(t);
  }
template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<
  !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, T &&>::type
  forward_as_ref(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type &&t) {
    return t;
  }
template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
  std::reference_wrapper<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>>::type
  forward_as_ref(T t) {
    return t;
  }
```

Here's a version using class template specialization instead:

```
template<typename T> struct forward_as_ref_type {
   typedef T &&type;
};
template<typename T> struct forward_as_ref_type<T &> {
   typedef std::reference_wrapper<T> type;
};

template<typename T> typename forward_as_ref_type<T>::type forward_as_ref(
   typename std::remove_reference<T>::type &t) {
      return static_cast<typename forward_as_ref_type<T>::type>(t);
   }
template<typename T> T &&forward_as_ref(
   typename std::remove_reference<T>::type &&t) {
      return t;
   }
```